# Remove all text in between a div without losing text outside of it - jQuery JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some text that is stored in a variable like this:

```
<div class="foo">text inside div</div>
outside text here.
```

I want to remove the entire div and the text in it and save the outside text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an element based off the HTML.  Then,

```
$('.foo', context).remove();
```

For example:

```
var text = "<div class=\"foo\">text inside div</div>\noutside text here.";
var xml = $('<root>' + text + '</root>');
$('.foo', xml).remove();
text = xml.html();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`after`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/after), to insert the inner text after the div, and then remove it:

```
var $foo = $(".foo"); 
$foo.after($foo.text()).remove();
```

Or you could use the [`replaceWith`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/replaceWith) function, to replace the div element with its inner text content:

```
$foo.replaceWith($foo.text());
```